# How to get the value of a HTML5 video tag src attribute in Android

Tags: android, html, webview, video-streaming, html5-video

My application have a WebView. The WebView HTML has:

```
<video id="player" src="rtsp://somesite/videofile.mp4" >Video content</video>
```

How can I get the `src` attribute from this HTML?

I want to have the URI of this video. It's needed to play in my video player. I don't want to use VideoView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```
yourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('player').doSomething..
```

If you want to get the value out of your WebView, use

```
/* Register a new JavaScript interface called JSInterface */  
yourWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "JSInterface");
yourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.JSInterface.setSrc(document.getElementById('player').src)");
```

`setSrc` is a method in your Java class.